Exporting constants to QML
Hellow, everyone. I apologize in advance for my English.
Could someone help me? I don't understand why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong.
I have a separate class with static constants (currently string constants)
namespace constants {
Q_NAMESPACE

class SharedConstants : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString Property MEMBER Property CONSTANT)
public:
static inline const QString Property{"MY_PROPERTY_TEXT"};
};

} // namespace constants

In main.cpp, I expose it to QML using
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<constants::SharedConstants>(
    "Constants", 1, 0, "SharedConstants", "SharedConstants class is not createable");

And when I try to access my property in QML using
import Constants 1.0
...
console.info(SharedConstants.Property)

I get the output undefined.
I assume that the static class parameters were not somehow defined in QML, but I don't understand why.
Initially, I tried to simply expose constants to QML, assuming that I need to use import Constants. But I wasn't successful and decided to use the class as an auxiliary tool. However, even here, something is not working for me. Please help. If you know how to expose constants from a namespace to QML using import, I would also appreciate it.
I'm using Qt 5.15.2, C++17 standard.

Have you defined the static member outside the class in any other source file? Though you've used inline so that shouldn't be the problem. See this answer or this answer

Change SharedConstants.Property to SharedConstants::Property maybe?

@user12002570 Unfortunately this didn't work

Consider using qmlRegisterSingletonType(). Also, it's recommended that Q_PROPERTY begin with a lowercase.
// sharedconstants.h
#ifndef SHAREDCONSTANTS_H
#define SHAREDCONSTANTS_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QJSEngine>
namespace constants
{
    Q_NAMESPACE
class SharedConstants : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SharedConstants(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString prop MEMBER prop CONSTANT)
    static QObject* singletonProvider(QQmlEngine*, QJSEngine*)
    {
        return new SharedConstants();
    }
private:
    static inline const QString prop{"MY_PROPERTY_TEXT"};
};
}
#endif // SHAREDCONSTANTS_H

// main.cpp
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<constants::SharedConstants>("Constants", 1, 0, "SharedConstants", &constants::SharedConstants::singletonProvider);

// main.qml
import Constants 1.0
// ...
console.log(SharedConstants.prop);


Thank you very much! qmlRegisterSingletonType, as well as qmlRegisterSingletonInstance, worked!
